# How to Update Gitlab server's default homepage from localhost to MyGitlab.com

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, localhost, gitlab-ce

I have installed **Gitlab CE** server on **Ubuntu 20.04** at Virtual machine.
Now gitlab's homepage can be accessed and admin login is Successful by web browser on URL **localhost**.
I want to set this URL to **MyGitlab.com**. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution myself for this question.

Run this command on Terminal

```
sudo vim /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

and Changed this Line

```
external_url "https://gitlab.tecadmin.net"
```